# Simplest way to check if a command-line program is installed?

Tags: command-line, powershell

Specifically perl.
Something along the lines of

```
if(perl) { "You have perl installed, we may continue" }
```

Would be good, but it (understandably) runs the perl utility. Is there a way to  simply check if the perl command would be found in the current context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On unix, you could run the command `which perl` and if it returns something then you know you have a valid file.

```
$ which ftp
/usr/bin/ftp
$ which noexist
which: 0652-141 There is no noexist in /usr/local/bin /usr/dlc/bin /usr/bin /etc
 /usr/sbin /usr/ucb /home/glowcoder/bin /usr/bin/X11 /sbin ..
$
```

Comment: It is important to try `Get-Command perl.exe` just in case there are is a function with that name.

Comment: IMO, this is not at all an answer to this question. Neither works on cmd nor on Powershell. Though it does suggest an approach for doing this.

Comment: @manojlds - It however allowed me to figure out the answer which is the first posted comment

Answer (score 1):

In Windows cmd, you would use `where` command which is the "equivalent" of `which` in *nix.

Unfortunately, you cannot use it like that in Powershell, since in Powershell, `where` is alias for `Where-Object`

Once alternative is to call it as `where.exe`:

```
where.exe perl
```

Note that this is based on the exe / program being on PATH.

And `Get-command` is the "equivalent" in Powershell, which is of course, much more powerful.